# What characters are unsafe in query strings?

Tags: query-string, security

I need to prevent the characters that cause vulnerabilities in the URL.

My sample URL is *http://localhost/add.aspx?id=4;req=4*.

Please give the list of characters that I need block.

I am using an [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) web page. I am binding the information from an [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database.

I just want to list the characters to stay away from *hackers* to enter unwanted strings in the URL.

Comment: You need to give more info. It really depends on how the data is being used. If for example your pulling the value of id and generating a dynamic sql query for MSSQL, that would be different then if your doing an LDAP lookup etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what technology you're using, there is usually a built-in function that will handle this for you.

**ASP.NET (VB) & Classic ASP**

```
myUrl = Server.UrlEncode(myUrl)
```

**ASP.NET (C#)**

```
myUrl = Server.UrlEncode(myUrl);
```

**PHP**

```
$myUrl = urlencode($myurl);
```

---

If you simply would like to **remove unsafe characters**, you would need a regular expression. [RFC 1738](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1738.txt) defines what characters are unsafe for URLs:

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a
>   number of reasons.  The space
>   character is unsafe because
>   significant spaces may disappear and
>   insignificant spaces may be introduced
>   when URLs are transcribed or
>   typeset or subjected to the treatment
>   of word-processing programs.    The
>   characters "<" and ">" are unsafe
>   because they are used as the
>   delimiters around URLs in free text;
>   the quote mark (""") is used to
>   delimit URLs in some systems.  The
>   character "#" is unsafe and should
>   always be encoded because it is used
>   in World Wide Web and in other
>   systems to delimit a URL from a
>   fragment/anchor identifier that might 
>   follow it.  The character "%" is
>   unsafe because it is used for
>   encodings of other characters.  Other
>   characters are unsafe because
>   gateways and other transport agents
>   are known to sometimes modify    such
>   characters. These characters are "{",
>   "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",    "[", "]",
>   and "`".

Comment: @Terrapin  I need to filter some unwanted characters no need for me to encode. Please suggest

Comment: If you want to completely filer out bad characters, you'll need to use Regular Expressions. If you want to simply translate (encode) those characters into safe ones, use URL Encoding.

Comment: @Terrapin. I have wrote these to replace this (-^{}[];$=*`#|@'\<>()+,\\)with empty string. Please check whether this is correct

Answer (score 4):

> I need to prevent the characters that cause vulnerabilities

Well, of course you *need* to URL encode, as the answers have said. But does *not* URL encoding cause vulnerabilities? Well, normally not directly; mostly it just makes your application break when unexpected characters are input.

If we're talking about web ‘vulnerabilities’, the most common ones today are:

1. Server-side [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), compromising your server
2. [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), compromising your database
3. HTML injection, allowing [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks against your users
4. Unvalidated actions, allowing [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (XSRF) attacks against your users

These are in order of decreasing seriousness and increasing commonness. (Luckily few web site authors are stupid enough to be passing user input to system() these days, but XSS and XSRF vulnerabilities are rife.)

Each of these vulnerabilities requires you to understand the underlying problem and cope with it deliberately. There is no magic list of “strings you need to block” that will protect your application if it is playing naïve about security. There *are* some add-ons that do things like blocking the string ‘<script>’ when submitted, but all they give you is a false sense of security since they can only catch a few common cases, and are usually easy to code around.

They'll also stop those strings being submitted when you might genuinely want them. For example, some (stupid) PHP authors refuse all incoming apostrophes as an attempt to curb SQL-injection; result is you can't be called “O'Reilly”. D'oh. Don't block; encode properly.

For example, to protect against SQL injection make sure to SQL-escape any strings that you are making queries with (or use parameterised queries to do this automatically); to protect against HTML injection, HTML-encode all text strings you output onto the page (or use a templating/MVC scheme that will do this automatically).

> My sample URL http://localhost/add.aspx?id=4;req=4

Is there supposed to be something wrong with that URL? It's valid to separate two query parameters with a ‘;’ instead of the more common ‘&’, but many common web frameworks lamentably still don't understand this syntax by default (including Java Servlet and ASP.NET). So you'd have to go with ‘id=4&req=4’ — or, if you really wanted that to be a single parameter with a literal semicolon in it, ‘id=4%3Breq%3D4’.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

See also: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2

Comment: I just ask about what are the strings that are i need to block

Comment: It's still valuable as a reference. Added RFC.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this, for pretty URLs, but it's of course not complete:

""",´,’,·,‚,*,@,?,=,;,:,.,/,+,&,$,<,>,#,%,{,(,),},|,,^,~,[,],—,–,-',,"

And then I translate spaces " " and repeating spaces for "-".

A better thing is to do it or combine it with a regular expression.